# Updating flink keyby function in production

Tags: java, deployment, streaming, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm attempting to update a keyby function in one of my production flink jobs by adding a new keyby value to the getKey function e.g. the keyby function was

```
return Tuple2.of(
        value.getTimestamp(),
        value.isDefault()
```

and now it is

```
return Tuple3.of(
        value.getTimestamp(),
        value.isDefault(),
        value.isRedirect()
)
```

I am attempting to deploy to my new job to the uat server (to make sure it works before going to prod) by stopping the job gracefully and resuming with a savepoint however I get the following error:

> java.lang.Exception: Exception while creating StreamOperatorStateContext. Caused by: org.apache.flink.util.FlinkException: Could not restore keyed state backend for WindowOperator_0dd2cd57af65cb839540855ced2e4169_(1/1) from any of the 1 provided restore options

However, it works if I resume the job (with the new key by function) but without a savepoint.

My best educated guess from the error is that the savepoint contained data that was using the old keyby function and now there is a new one and they are not compatible.

However this begs the question, how does one update a keyby function on a production flink job while stopping the job gracefully?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The built-in schema migration support in Flink specifically disallows changes to the key because the new key function might have a different key group assignment.

I believe the only way to do a stateful upgrade when updating the keyBy function is to use the [State Processor API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/libs/state_processor_api/) to rewrite the savepoint.

There's a simple example of using that API to dump state from a checkpoint [here](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/state-processor/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/training/exercises/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java). That might help you get started.

Comment: I think I was able to do this. However is it normal to have to run the job with "allow non-restored state" because now the original keyby function doesnt exist?